# Normalizing A Numpy Arange

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normalize

I am just beginning to program in python. I would like to normalize a numpy arange for various functions. My code so far is

```
from numpy import arange
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function_A(x):
    return -(x-1)*(x-5)

def normalize(functionName, numpyRange):
    print "Inside normalize"

    min = numpyRange.min()
    max = numpyRange.max()

    print "functionName: ", functionName
    print "min: ", min
    print "max: ", max
    print "quad(functionName, min, max)[0]: ", quad(functionName, min, max)[0]
    print "functionName(numpyRange): ", functionName(numpyRange) 

    print "RIGHT BEFORE RETURN"

    return functionName(numpyRange) / quad(functionName, min, max)[0]

x = arange(1,5.01,0.01)
plt.plot(x, normalize(function_A, x))
plt.show()

print "This should equal unity: ", quad(normalize(function_A, x), x.min(), x.max(), args=(function_A, x))
```

The error message when I run my code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forStackExchange3.py", line 33, in <module>
    print "This should equal unity: ", quad(normalize(function_A, x), x.min(), x.max(), args=(function_A, x))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 247, in quad
    retval = _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 312, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
quadpack.error: First argument must be a callable function.
```

The error message is confusing to me because even though the error occurs on the line

```
print "This should equal unity: ", quad(normalize(function_A, x), x.min(), x.max(), args=(function_A, x))
```

I am still able to "enter" my normalize function, as evidenced by my multiple print statements. I have tried experimenting with different ways of writing the line that is giving the error message, but have not had any luck. Any help would be appreciated. Perhaps I need to rewrite my normalize function so that I can correctly use quad? Also, if there is a simpler method for normalizing functions in python for my particular case, please let me know.

Comment: Note that numpy `arange` is not consistent with non-integer step sizes. The documentation recommends `linspace` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `quad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) states:

> func : function A Python function or method to integrate.

However, the first argument you pass is an `ndarray`, which is not callable. In other words, you are not passing the function you want to integrate, but rather the result of some other such operation.

---

That's for what was technically wrong. As to how to fix it, I must say that I'm not sure what you're asking. Given a range `y`, it's possible to normalize it. The range `y` *might* be the result of applying some function to `x`, but that's besides the point. So you can build a range normalizer, and apply it to the results of functions.

```
def function_A(x):
    return -(x-1)*(x-5)

x = arange(1,5.01,0.01)

def normalize(y):
    return y / sum(y)

>> sum(normalize(function_A(x)))
1.0
```

You could also build a meta-function, which takes a function and returns a function that normalizes its results:

```
def make_normalized(fn):
    return lambda x: fn(x) / sum(fn(x))
```

So, with that, you could define

```
normalized_function_A = make_normalized(function_A)
```

and just to verify:

```
>> sum(normalized_function_A(x))
1.0
```